# What is the JCAMP-DX data format?

Tags: file, csv, format

I have an instrument that outputs jcamp-dx (*.jdx) files. There is software I can use to view the data, but I would rather do some other things with it, like plot it on web pages, which isn't allowed in the software I have to access the data.

The data files are plain text, but they have some weird format I haven't deciphered yet.
A complete data file [here:](http://pastebin.com/SuDMnE9G)

The first part is clearly a header, noting the instrument setup.
dataset excerpt:

```
##DATA TABLE=       (X++(R..R)), XYDATA     $$ real data
0B11342B85545C23989C17351B74931B05470A26105D9294a1056e3313g0949f8969e3550c7777
0.003500000108b6949b6475c8140f4800i9368a29728a55860a65707a61314a41319a07814
0.006250000093f4324a7318C0833G6565A17668A50784A82638B02193B14577B15248A98749
0.008999999613A67352A16985D8866c0263a07145a73892b26727b51285b50303b20050a63440
...
```

one might think that the data table would be some sort of csv, unfortunately I do not see this.
the next like isnt like the other lines, so assume it is a check sum or some encoded string.
the other 3 lines (and other like them there after) seem to have a pattern, unfortunately I have no idea how to decode them into meaningful data.
I'm sure I could figure it out given enough time, but I am hoping that someone more skilled can just point out the structure to me.

```
0.008999999613, A67352, A16985, D8866, c0263, a07145, a73892, b26727, b51285, b50303, b20050, a63440,
```

I can see there are 5 digits after each letter.
no idea what the letters mean, they seem to vary.
maybe Capital A is a positive number and lowercase a is a negative.
what would X++  be a counter?

X, Y, I gues that makes sense. then $$real Data? what like intensity?
then later it get down a page and the data table changes to:

```
##DATA TABLE=       (X++(I..I)), XYDATA     $$ imaginary data
```

I can see that the data tables are 197 strings long, as well.
But I'm still just guessing about the actual meaning of the data, and its format.

Can anyone assist me here? Any chemists in here? Ideas? 
Causing some confusion for me is the variations in the letters between each set of numbers.

Yes I see http://www.jcamp-dx.org/
but I do not see any place that discusses the data format.

Are there any open source tools that do conversions for jdx to csv?
I am just looking for something to help me grok the format. 
please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sure looks like the format is described in PDFs linked from that site's "Standards" nav link.

http://www.jcamp-dx.org/protocols.html

- [JCAMP-DX for Infrared 4.24 (1988)](http://www.jcamp-dx.org/protocols/dxir01.pdf)
- [JCAMP-CS for chemical structure (1991)](http://www.jcamp-dx.org/protocols/dxcs01.pdf)
- [JCAMP-DX for NMR (1993)](http://www.jcamp-dx.org/protocols/dxnmr01.pdf)
- [JCAMP-DX for MS (1994)](http://www.jcamp-dx.org/protocols/dxms01.pdf)
- [JCAMP-DX extension 5.01 (1999)](http://www.jcamp-dx.org/protocols/dx5-01-correctedv2.pdf)
- [JCAMP-DX for IMS (2001)](http://www.jcamp-dx.org/protocols/ims-dx%20PAC%2073(11)%20pp1765-1782%202001.pdf)
- [NMR Pulse Sequence Definitions (2001)](http://www.jcamp-dx.org/protocols/NMR%20Pulse%20Sequences%20PAC%2079(11)%20pp1748-1764%202001.pdf)

Comment: http://www.jcamp-dx.org/protocols/NMR%20Pulse%20Sequences%20PAC%2079%2811%29%20pp1748-1764%202001.pdf

reading

Comment: @j0h did you make any progress with this problem?

Comment: @j0h you may be able to get some information from the author of this package, http://hyperspec.r-forge.r-project.org/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I have found out about JCAMP-DX. 
It is a plain text data file. 
I have a .jdx file that is a CO2 absorption spectrum measured in the infra red band. 
The .jdx file is easily opened in Gnumeric spreadsheet. 
The .jdx file is easily opened in Gnuplot after editing the file to put a # in front of any comment lines that do not have an initial #.

To my great delight, without even reading the comments, the CO2 absorption spectrum file opened with the x and y units I wanted.

Gnuplot 4.6 on Ubuntu Linux. 
gnuplot> plot 'co2.jdx'      ; Bingo!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was available when this question was originally published, but there is a python module that converts JCAMP-DX data to a dictionary of its X and Y data.

https://github.com/nzhagen/jcamp

From their documentation:

> The `jcamp_reader()` function takes a filename as input, and returns a dictionary containing the data found in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question was posted years ago, I just stumbled across it *and* a possible solution, though it requires proprietary software.

Turns out, MATLAB (R2017a, for me) has the [built-in ability](https://de.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/jcampread.html) to open these data.

You can just run

```
JCAMPStruct = jcampread(File)
```

where file refers to a "Character vector specifying a file name, a path and file name, or a URL pointing to a file." (I am quoting the help from the link here).
This was super useful to me, because then I could just extract the X (wavenumber) and Y (transmittance) by accessing `JCAMPStruct.Blocks.Xdata` and `...Ydata` respectively.

For anyone who has access to MATLAB (if you work in academia, your institute might have it licensed...), this should be an easy fix.